# How can I assign a value to a different column for each row in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `dat` that looks like this:

```
        p1    p2    type  replace
1       0     1     1     1
2       1     0     1     1
3       0     0     2     1
...
```

I want do something like `dat['p + str(type)'] = replace` to get:

```
        p1    p2    type  replace 
1       1     1     1     1
2       1     0     1     1
3       0     1     2     1
...
```

How can I do this?  Of course I can't assign in a loop using something like iterrows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is some one liner to do this, but if performance is not really an issue, you can easily do this with a simple for loop:

```
In [134]: df
Out[134]: 
   p1  p2  type  replace
0   0   1     1        1
1   1   0     1        1
2   0   0     2        1

In [135]: for i in df.index:
     ...:     df.loc[i, 'p'+str(df.loc[i, 'type'])] = df.loc[i, 'replace']

In [136]: df
Out[136]: 
   p1  p2  type  replace
0   1   1     1        1
1   1   0     1        1
2   0   1     2        1
```

If you have much more rows than columns, this will be much faster and is actually easier (and if necessary you can loop over 1, 2, ..):

```
df["p1"][df["type"]==1] = df["replace"][df["type"]==1]
df["p2"][df["type"]==2] = df["replace"][df["type"]==2]
```

Comment: Thanks, anything that works is a good first step!  I'd vote you up but I don't have the karma yet :)

Comment: I wonder if I could find something a bit faster, though...I'm going to keep the question open just a bit longer before I accept your solution.

Comment: You don't see an empty 'v' to the left of my answer?

Comment: Lol, I'm a noob.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
In [47]: df['p1'].where(~(df['type'] == 1), df['replace'], inplace=True)

In [48]: df['p2'].where(~(df['type'] == 2), df['replace'], inplace=True)

In [49]: df
Out[49]: 
   p1  p2  type  replace
1   1   1     1        1
2   1   0     1        1
3   0   1     2        1
```

Comment: joris's new answer is more straightforward and probably just as fast.

Comment: Thanks!  It looks like there is no quick way to do this -- I think I will try to reformulate the problem so this step isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, I ended up doing the following, which may or may not be the same as what Dan Allan suggested:

```
for i in range(2):
    df.loc[df['type'] == i + 1, 'p' + str(i + 1)] = df.loc[df['type'] == i + 1, 'replace']
```

I have a much larger problem than the example I gave (with something like 30 types and thousands of rows in the dataframe), and this solution seems very fast.  Thanks to all for your help in thinking about this problem!